# Is there any way to get a Bearer token now, since Robinhood has changed the API again?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, authorization, algorithmic-trading

We keep playing this cat and mouse game with Robinhood.com.  I have a trading app which used to trade stocks with Robinhood, but they keep changing the unsupported unofficial API to make it difficult for traders to use.  I know that many people are doing the same thing and I want to reach out to them to see if there is a new answer.  The latest problem is when I try to get a Bearer token using the URL https://api.robinhood.com/oauth2/token/ the API returns the following JSON: {"detail":"This version of Robinhood is no longer supported. Please update your app or use Robinhood for Web to log in to your account."}.  This started happening on 4/26/2019.

Has anyone found a work around for this, yet, or have they finally beaten us into submission?

Comment: checkiin in the indexedDb in location . There you will find it

Answer (score 2):

A more complete solution (not need browser):
Use `requests.session`.

1. Obtain the login page by making a GET request to "https://robinhood.com/login".
   At this point the session's cookies will contain 'device_id'.
2. Obtain this device_id and use it in making the oauth2 token request to "https://api.robinhood.com/oauth2/token/" also add in the data request "challenge_type" (either "sms" or "email").
   This request will fail with a 400 error code. Robinhood will send an SMS message or Email with a temporary (5 minute) code.
   Also at this point use the 400 response's body to get "id" from "challenge" inside of the JSON object.
3. Confirm the challenge by making a POST request to "https://api.robinhood.com/challenge/CHALLENGEID/respond/" where CHALLENGEID is the same id mentioned in the first failed /oauth2/token/ POST request.
4. Make the same POST request to "https://api.robinhood.com/oauth2/token/" and include in the header "X-ROBINHOOD-CHALLENGE-RESPONSE-ID" with the value CHALLENGEID.

You can reuse a device_id with user/pass after this even after logging out.
Be cautious with storing device_id as it is the result of user/pass login and successful SMS/email 2FA.

Answer (score 1):

Just got it working.  At the risk of them seeing this post and changing it more, here we go:

1. First, you're going to want to log into your RH account in a web browser
2. View Source on the page, and look for `clientId` - it should be a big hex number separated by dashes
3. Add that number to your POST requests to `/oauth2/token` under the field `device_token`

There's probably another way to retrieve the device token, and I'm not even sure it's unique, but that way should work.

Comment: Great! Same show-stopper problem! My old stock engine relies on [RobinhoodShell](https://github.com/anilshanbhag/RobinhoodShell/issues/22) and more importantly, [robinhood-python](https://github.com/mstrum/robinhood-python/issues/34) for options.  Via script I can generate an auth code to email, and catch that Gmail from Linux, but am still out of my league to fix those projects.

Comment: I didn't know robinhood-python existed, and it looks like I basically reinvented that particular wheel.  ;)  From what I can see on their GitHub page, they arrived at basically the same solution as me - which isn't ideal - where you can retrieve your device token through the hacky way above and pass it in as a parameter to the required functions.   At some point it would be nice to find a way to automate the retrieval of the device token, but it doesn't look like anyone has that solution yet.

Comment: http://forked.yannick.io/mstrum/robinhood-python is a somewhat abandoned project; the author is aware but has no time to address the recent stricter login.  Any chance you'd fork it and know how to implement the workarounds they made in [fast_arrow](https://github.com/westonplatter/fast_arrow/issues/85) and [robinhood-node](https://github.com/aurbano/robinhood-node/issues/100) ?  I'm attempting to learn enough Python to try myself :/

Comment: I can't find the clientID in the source code on the robinhood.com page. The page is pretty short, so I don't think I would be missing it, but I'm not exactly sure what to be looking for. Is this method still viable?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jmfernandes/robin_stocks

I just reimplemented this and used the above as a reference.  The client ID  is isn’t unique, I’m guessing it corresponds to app version.  You also need a device token now, but that’s just a random hex string - generate once, save it somewhere, and pass it with your requests.

Answer (score 0):

Good to be back here after a very long time.
Not sure if anyone is still looking for answers to this, but I have a very simple solution.

At Robinhood's login screen, enter your username/email and your password, press F12 on your keyboard to bring up the console panel and switch to the "Network" tab then wait for the page to load completely. (During this time you will see a list of items being loaded rapidly depending on the connection speed.)

At this time you can keep clearing the list by clicking on the button highlighted in the below image.

[Click on button highlighted repeatedly until the list is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGoQn.png)

Now, log into your Robinhood account. At this point your console should display a list similar to the one shown below.

[Look for the name "token/", most likely it will be the second one you get all the information you need. And this information will be under the **Headers** then **Request Payload**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRDLS.png)

I was able to find this with past knowledge and experience of web scraping for fun. And also, I needed to know this as well, since I recently started doing trades via Robinhood.

Hope this help you curious ones out there.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to GET positions and the credentials needed?

Answer (score 0):

For my Robinhood account I am using Google Authenticator for my 2FA.  What I have so far is that I send the original call that I was sending before to https://api.robinhood.com/oauth2/token/.  This is giving me a response of:

```
{"mfa_required":true,"mfa_type":"app"}
```

I then repeat my oauth token request, but this time providing the value from Google Authenticator (so my GUI has to prompt me to fill it in) with this payload in the request to https://api.robinhood.com/oauth2/token/:

```
{"grant_type":"password","scope":"internal","client_id":"c82SH0WZOsabOXGP2sxqcj34FxkvfnWRZBKlBjFS","expires_in":86400,"device_token":"***","username":"***","password":"****","mfa_code":"***"}
```

and then I am getting an access token in reply